# Small panel - Deforestation

Tags: panel-data, least-squares, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, small-sample

I am trying to empirically test the relationship between certain drivers of deforestation (independent variables) and deforestation in a small developing country.

I have data for 4 provinces and for 8 years, so it is an extremely small panel, thus I do acknowledge the fact that its results may have small explanatory power, but do emphasize that: the 4 provinces hold 100% of the forest, 63% of total deforestation occurred in the studied period (1984 to 1999), and my 8 observations are within that period in non consecutive years.

I have used pooled OLS, RE and FE (clustered and non clustered). Results are as expect with regards to sign and significance.

Is it then fair to say that evidence seems to suggest a linkage between the proposed drivers and deforestation?  I do say that FE results and clustered models might be less than ideal given the small panel. And overall endogeneity is not controled for (even if I do use some control variables, and the independent variables used are exogenously determined - AK international commodity price), but all models seem to serve as evidence since results are consistent with theory and literature.

I'll be happy to listen to criticisms - Oh specification is Log-Log.

Comment: Providing a sample of the actual data would also be helpful